# How to find if a data set can train a neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

Some experimental data contains 512 independent boolean features and a boolean result.

There are about 1e6 real experiment records in the provided data set.

In a classic XOR example all 4 out of 4 possible states are required to train NN. In my case its only `2^(10-512) = 2^-505` which is close to zero.

I have no more information about the data nature, just these `(512 + 1) * 1e6` bits.

Tried NN with 1 hidden layer on available data. Output of the trained NN on the samples even from the training set are always close to 0, not a single close to "1". Played with weights initialization, gradient descent learning rate.

My [code](https://pastebin.com/9uM6gDR3) utilizing TensorFlow 1.3, Python 3. Model excerpt:

```
with tf.name_scope("Layer1"):
    #W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([512, innerN], minval=-2/512, maxval=2/512), name="Weights_1")
    W1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([512, innerN]), name="Weights_1")
    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), name="Bias_1")
    
    Out1 = tf.sigmoid( tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1)

with tf.name_scope("Layer2"):
    W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([innerN, 1], minval=-2/512, maxval=2/512), name="Weights_2")
    #W2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([innerN, 1]), name="Weights_2")
    b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), name="Bias_2")
    
    y = tf.nn.sigmoid( tf.matmul(Out1, W2) + b2)

with tf.name_scope("Training"):
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
    
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            labels = y_, logits = y)
    )

    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.005).minimize(cross_entropy)
    
with tf.name_scope("Testing"):
    # Test trained model
    correct_prediction = tf.equal( tf.round(y), tf.round(y_))
# ...
# Train
for step in range(500):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = Datasets.train.next_batch(300, shuffle=False)
    _, my_y, summary = sess.run([train_step, y, merged_summaries],
        feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
```

I suspect two cases:

1. my fault – bad NN implementation, wrong architecture;
2. bad data. Compared to XOR example, incomplete training data would result in a failing NN. However, the training examples fed to the trained NN are supposed to give right predictions, aren't they?

**How to evaluate** if it is possible at all to train a neural network (a 2-layer perceptron) on the provided data to forecast the result? A case of aceptable set would be the XOR example. Opposed to some random noise.

Comment: I wouldn't be inclined to use a neural network for data that consists only of boolean inputs.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What is a better aproach in this case?

Comment: I would start with a decision tree and quickly switch to random forests.  Depending on the nature of the data, you might have luck with SVMs (depending on the structure of the data), but I think random forests would likely do a better job.

Comment: what if the data has no correlation at all? I.e. experiments outcome was in fact caused by some other factor beyond the feature set?

Comment: I agree with Gordon's comment, however, I think that you also can start with xgboost from the beginning to save your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only ad hoc ways to know if it is possible to learn a function with a differentiable network from a dataset. That said, these ad hoc ways do usually work. For example, the network should be able to overfit the training set without any regularisation.

A common technique to gauge this is to only fit the network on a subset of the full dataset. Check that the network can overfit to that, then increase the size of the subset, and increase the size of the network as well. Unfortunately, deciding whether to add extra layers or add more units in a hidden layer is an arbitrary decision you'll have to make.

However, looking at your code, there are a few things that could be going wrong here:

1. Are your outputs balanced? By that I mean, do you have the same number of 1s as 0s in the dataset targets?
2. Your initialisation in the first layer is all zeros, the gradient to this will be zero, so it can't learn anything (although, you have a real initialisation above it commented out).
3. Sigmoid nonlinearities are more difficult to optimise than simpler nonlinearities, such as ReLUs.

I'd recommend using the [built-in definitions for layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.layers) in Tensorflow to not worry about initialisation, and switching to ReLUs in any hidden layers (you need sigmoid at the output for your boolean target).

Finally, deep learning isn't actually very good at most "bag of features" machine learning problems because they lack structure. For example, the order of the features doesn't matter. Other methods often work better, but if you really want to use deep learning then you could look at [this recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.02515), showing improved performance by just using a very specific nonlinearity and weight initialisation (change 4 lines in your code above).

Comment: 1. outputs are balanced, verified.
 2. sure I have tried with random normal init as well;
 
Trying random forest aproach now, it takes long. Waiting for first results, while the CPU is 100% loaded and fans are spinning aloud.

Comment: You might want to try Naive Bayes, given you have boolean inputs and targets. It will run much faster ([closed form and linear time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier)) than the random forest, and is optimal under conditional independence assumptions.

Comment: Thanks again! Random forest eventually gave a miserable 0.5239 accuracy after ~1 hour CPU heating. [Tried the Naive Bayes](https://gist.github.com/sergiks/f3197087b53eeca153b9c4cad3e25a7e) as well, which yilded 0.47 accuracy. Either I am doing something wrong or the data is not suiable for ML algorithms..

Comment: That's very strange, if your classes are balanced then you can get 0.5 accuracy by just guessing one class all the time, so something must be going wrong. Is that accuracy on the training data, or on validation?

Comment: I got 600 000 samples dataset. The Random Forest 0.52 accuracy was on samples from the training set. Used all 6e5 samples to train, first 6e4 out of those to validate. 
The Naive Bayes 0.47 – on validation 100 samples, separate from 599900 training ones.